# How to handle multiple push notifications received when iOS app is in FOREGROUND using iOS 6+

Tags: ios6, apple-push-notifications

In my iOS app , server sends push notifications for multiple types. Now lets say my **app is in foreground** & user is using my app. If server sends multiple push notifications to this user at once , how can I show & process those push notification ?

I thought of showing alert views for push notifications but its showing multiple alert views continuously since I have multiple push notifications. Also I need to distinguish between payload so that I can load show correct info to user.

Now my questions are

1) What is the best way to handle multiple push notification received simultaneously ?

2) Can I implement something like inbuilt push notifications banner? Does Apple allow this ? If yes , any reference would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.