# Handling issue while receiving multiples notifications at the same time

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-pushplugin

I use Cordova/PhoneGap and the [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin).
Everything works, except when I receive several notifications at the same time for my app while this one is in background.

Let's say I receive notification A and notification B.
When I click on A, B is ignored. Indeed, the app opens and only A is handled.
Meaning that the Javascript callback `onNotificationAPN` is only fired for A.

How to handle both, no matter what was the notification clicked?

It's important I solve it since it would lead to some unprocessed notifications.

Comment: I managed to find a way to handle the whole thanks to the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831819/how-to-handle-multiple-push-notifications-received-when-ios-app-is-in-foreground:  no matter what notification comes, I refresh the whole concerned data.

Comment: You could add your answer and accept it